# IndexError: list index out of range Python/Anaconda

Tags: python

I keep getting the error:

```
D:\anaconda-master\tools>bimbam.py "C:\MFATEST.exe" "C:\Output"
Bimbam tool by Mathias Kaerlev
ONLY for use on your own applications.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda-master\tools\bimbam.py", line 69, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\anaconda-master\tools\bimbam.py", line 35, in main
    input = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried to decompile my lost game on Fusion and I can't get this to work please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sys.argv is a list of strings representing the arguments provided to your script, in this case, the main method.

The error is telling you there is nothing inside sys.argv[1]

Try this and check which arguments are you receiving actually:

```
print(sys.argv)
```

Comment: D:\anaconda-master\tools>print(sys.argv)
Unable to initialize device PRN
???
sorry if i dont understand

Comment: Sorry if I didnt explain myself correctly. Your file D:\anaconda-master\tools\bimbam.py is a python script file which is readable. You can actually see in your Traceback the lines where the error occurs. So before the line 35 you should add print(sys.argv)

Comment: Actually try this in your shell <path of your python bin> <path of your file> <argument 1> <argument 2>

Comment: What i need to put in argument ? 
sorry i bother you much

Comment: As I can see here https://github.com/matpow2/anaconda/blob/master/tools/bimbam.py You have to provide input and output. I think your arguments are fine but you have to add the <path of your python bin> before D:\anaconda-master\tools>bimbam.py to tell Python to execute that script.

Comment: Also try the print(sys.argv) because I am not sure if the script is receiving correctly the arguments.

Comment: no matter what i do if the wod "bimbam" is in the command its runs the same problem

Comment: yes i do i just dont know nothing about this i just wanted to recover my project

Comment: Maybe you should check this link, it explains how to run your python script http://www.pythoncentral.io/execute-python-script-file-shell/
Also about the arguments. print(sys.argv) written before the line 35 will tell you in the shell the arguments provided, if you dont see anything try writting this print("Arguments %s" % sys.argv) and see if the word Arguments appears. Aso sys.argv[0] is the script, sys.argv[1] should be "C:\MFATEST.exe" and sys.argv[2] should be "C:\Output".

Comment: D:\Python27>python.exe D:\anaconda-master\tools\bimbam.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda-master\tools\bimbam.py", line 21, in <module>
    from mmfparser.data.exe import ExecutableData
ImportError: No module named mmfparser.data.exe

i executed python script and it gave me this ?????

Comment: The problem is the python you are using is not the anaconda's version. You have to install or find your anaconda's version which has the module mmfparser and execute your script with that bin

Comment: i did it and got the same error! i checekd that that "exe.py" is existed and it is! so what is the problem!?

Comment: There must be something wrong in your anaconda set up since mmfparser module is a basic anaconda module... https://github.com/matpow2/anaconda/tree/master/mmfparser